# How to disable SCSS compilation files in .NET Framework projects

Tags: css, webpack, sass, compilation, visual-studio-2017

I am developing an angular JS application with webpack using TypeScript and SCSS files, so when I compile the solution I want to VS not create .js and css files.

Adding these lines in the csproj of the projects the .js files are not created after compiling:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And now I want the same for the .css files.

I am using Visual studio Professional 2017.
The projects are developed using the version 4.5.2 of .NET Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio does not do SCSS compilation by default.  You've likely installed an extension which provides this functionality like the [Web Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler) extension.  Try disabling or removing the extension that is doing this to prevent the behavior.

Comment: I've just disabled Web Compiler and Web Essentials but it still creating these files

Answer (score 0):

**Solution.**

As Jimmy said, I have installed "BuildWebCompiler". After uninstall that nuget Packaged css files aren't generate when I compile the solution